# cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am getting the following error when trying to install perl's Encode::Detect module using this command

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Encode::Detect"
```

Error message

```
cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I googled a couple of things and i found out that i don't have g++ installed even if i had the following c compliers (gcc,c,c++).

To fix this i installed g++ complier on my ubuntu machine using

```
apt-get install g++
```

On RedHat and CentOS it will be

```
yum install g++
```